# Converting a \u escaped Unicode string to ASCII

Tags: r, unicode, text-processing, iconv, unicode-string

After reading all about `iconv` and `Encoding`, I am still confused.

I am scraping the source of a [web page](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pretty%3D%3Ebig&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15) I have a string that looks like this: `'pretty\u003D\u003Ebig'` (displayed in the R console as `'pretty\\\u003D\\\u003Ebig'`). I want to convert this to the ASCII string, which should be `'pretty=>big'`.

More simply, if I set

```
x <- 'pretty\\u003D\\u003Ebig'
```

How do I perform a conversion on `x` to yield `pretty=>big`?

Any suggestions?

Comment: The code you are using might be needed to replicate this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use parse, but don't evaluate the results:

```
x1 <- 'pretty\\u003D\\u003Ebig'
x2 <- parse(text = paste0("'", x1, "'"))
x3 <- x2[[1]]
x3
# [1] "pretty=>big"
is.character(x3)
# [1] TRUE
length(x3)
# [1] 1
```

Comment: `as.character(x2)` will work too and will be vectorized (i.e.: `as.character(parse(text=paste0("'", rep(x1,3), "'")))`). Also `shQuote(x1)` could be handy instead of `paste0`.

Answer (score 9):

With the `stringi` package:

```
> x <- 'pretty\\u003D\\u003Ebig'
> stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(x)
[1] "pretty=>big"
```

Answer (score 4):

Although I have accepted Hong ooi's answer, I can't help thinking `parse` and `eval` is a heavyweight solution. Also, as pointed out, it is not secure, although for my application I can be confident that I will not get dangerous quotes.

So, I have devised an alternative, somewhat brutal, approach:

```
udecode <- function(string){
  uconv <- function(chars) intToUtf8(strtoi(chars, 16L))
  ufilter <- function(string) {
    if (substr(string, 1, 1)=="|") uconv(substr(string, 2, 5)) else string
  }
  string <- gsub("\\\\u([[:xdigit:]]{4})", ",|\\1,", string, perl=TRUE)
  strings <- unlist(strsplit(string, ","))
  string <- paste(sapply(strings, ufilter), collapse='')
  return(string)
}
```

Any simplifications welcomed!

Answer (score 2):

A use for `eval(parse)`!

```
eval(parse(text=paste0("'", x, "'")))
```

This has its own problems of course, such as having to manually escape any quote marks within the string. But it should work for any valid Unicode sequences that may appear.

Comment: Fortunately, given the [source of the strings](x <- 'pretty\\u003D\\u003Ebig') quotes are already sanitised.

Comment: I have incorporated the fix into my [ngram package](https://github.com/seancarmody/ngramr). Thanks!

Comment: I've asked about sanitising here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770093/sanitising-strings-in-r

Comment: @HongOoi see my answer - just don't eval the result.

Answer (score 1):

I sympathise; I have struggled with R and unicode text in the past and not always successfully. If your data is in `x` then first try a global replace, something like this:

```
x <- gsub("\u003D", "=>", x)
```

I sometimes use a construction like

```
lapply(x, utf8ToInt)
```

to see where the high code points are e.g. anything over 150. This helps me locate problems caused by non-breaking spaces, for example, which seem to pop up every now and again.

Comment: I'd need to use `x <- gsub("\u003D\u003E", "=>", x)` but I'd rather not cover every possible case. Note that `lapply(x, utf8ToInt)` yields `112 114 101 116 116 121  92  48  48  51  68  92 117  48  48  51  69  98 105 103` so that they are all low code points! I just need to undo the \u escaping!

Comment: Ah, good point, I am usually tackling Asian scripts which do yield high points, this is clearly a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

```
> iconv('pretty\u003D\u003Ebig', "UTF-8", "ASCII")
[1] "pretty=>big"
```

but you appear to have an extra escape

Comment: Exactly! I can't help the extra escape: that's what the [web-page](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pretty%3D%3Ebig&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15) returns (click on it, view source and scroll down to the data).

Comment: It's also instructive to compare `cat('pretty\u003D\u003Ebig')` and `cat('pretty\\u003D\\u003Ebig')`. There is a big difference between escapes in data you enter at the console and escapes in data you obtain through other means.

Comment: are you using windows?

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that `'\\u003D'` is actually 6 characters while you want `'\u003D'` which is only one character. The further trick is that to match those backslashes you need to use doubly escaped backslashes in the pattern:

```
gsub("\\\\u003D\\\\u003E", "\u003D\u003E", x)
#[1] "pretty=>big"
```

To replace multiple characters with one character you need to target the entire pattern. You cannot simply delete a backslash. (Since you have indicated this is a more general problem, I think the answer might lie in modifications to your as yet undescribed method for downloading this text.)

When I load your functions and the dependencies, this code works:

```
> freq <- ngram(c('pretty\u003D\u003Ebig'), year_start = 1950)
> 
> str(freq)
'data.frame':   59 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Year     : num  1950 1951 1952 1953 1954 ...
 $ Phrase   : Factor w/ 1 level "pretty=>big": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Frequency: num  1.52e-10 6.03e-10 5.98e-10 8.27e-10 8.13e-10 ...
 $ Corpus   : Factor w/ 1 level "eng_2012": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

(So I guess I am still not clear on the use case.)

Comment: The gory detail of where the download is happening is [here](https://github.com/seancarmody/ngramr/blob/master/R/ngram.R), but just working with `x <- 'pretty\\u003D\\u003Ebig'` allows you to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I needed to identify the source for multiple missing function errors and loaded RCurl, stringr, httr, and RJSONIO before that would run. I tried with some of your commented code above those functions but am still not sure I have a test case to work on.

Comment: The relevant call that generates the error is `ngram("pretty=>big")`, but the reference to this package was to show the motivation only: it's too much for a reproducible example!

Comment: I should add that having accepted @Hong Ooi's solution, I the package no longer gives an error. Previously, a call to `ngram("pretty=>big")` would give `$ Phrase   : Factor w/ 1 level "pretty\u003D\u003Ebig"`.

Comment: Mind you, I am still interested in whether it can be done without `eval` and `parse`. The original example stands: assuming we have `x <- 'pretty\\u003D\\u003Ebig'` as a given and need to convert it to `'pretty=>big'`. Rather than the `ngramr` package, you can take the motivating example to be in the source of [this page](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pretty%3D%3Ebig&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15). View page search and search for `\u003D` and you'll find the problem!