# Sanitising strings in R

Tags: r, security, sanitization

This is related to a previous question, here: [Converting a \u escaped Unicode string to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17761858/474349)

I proposed a solution involving `eval(parse(text=x))`, which for non-R users, means what it says: parsing the text string, then evaluating it. The aim was *not* to allow arbitrary code to be executed, but only to un-escape escaped Unicode text. Hence the solution:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0("'", x, "'")))
```

While this should be fairly safe given the restricted objective, I'd be interested to know: how much sanitisation is required to keep things safe?

At a minimum, I guess any embedded single and double quotes have to be escaped. For example, suppose we have

```
x <- "this is a '; print(dir()); 'string"
```

Then `eval`'ing this per the snippet above would execute the code in the middle. So we have to escape the quotes:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0("'",
                       gsub("'", "\\\\'", x),
                       "'")))
```

And similarly for double quotes. I don't think the *unescaped* Unicode equivalents `\u0022` and `\u0027` are a problem, since to the parser they'll be identical to plain `"` and `'`.

Are there any holes in this approach that I've missed?

Comment: It would be good if there was a way to parse escaped strings without the machinery (and risk) of `eval`!

Comment: I have come up with an alternative without `eval`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17771985/1543437

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this is a \'; print(dir()); 'string
```

is escaped to:

```
'this is a \\'; print(dir()); 'string'
```

double-backslash is evaled as literal backslash, quote is active, code is executed.

Also I don't know about R but probably you could at minimum cause a crash using raw control characters like newline or invalid escapes.

`eval` is a mug's game in general. Normal string handling (search string for the sequence you want, replacing it) is the better approach, and using an existing library for a particular properly-specified format is best of all. For example if you have JSON, use a JSON parser. There are many possible string literal formats that use `\u` escapes, all with slightly different rules, so you will want to choose the exact format correctly.

Comment: Actually, the parser will give an error on that input, so the entire expression (including the embedded code) will never be evaluated. But that's not very good either....

Answer (score 0):

There is [`shQuote`](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/base/html/shQuote.html) function which could work for you:

```
eval(parse(text=shQuote(x)))
# [1] "this is a '; print(dir()); 'string"
```