# Display unicode in R

Tags: r, unicode

I have some unicode character that is stored as `"<U+9577><U+6D32>"`. Is it possible to convert it into `"\u9577\u6D32"`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
as.character(parse(text=shQuote(gsub("<U\\+([A-Z0-9]+)>", "\\\\u\\1", "<U+9577><U+6D32>"))))
```

([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761858/converting-a-u-escaped-unicode-string-to-ascii))

Comment: What if I have a column of such kind of unicode characters?

Comment: Pass the column instead of `"<U+9577><U+6D32>"`.