# Specify unicode characters programmatically R

Tags: r, utf-8

In R, you can specify unicode characters by using `\u` and then a code.

```
"\u00c3"
[1] "Ã"
```

What if I already have the "00c3" part as a string, how can I get the unicode?

```r
string <- "00c3"

paste0("\u", string)
#> Error: '\u' used without hex digits in character string starting ""\u"

paste0("\\u", string)
#> [1] "\\u00c3"

eval(paste0("\\u", string))
#> [1] "\\u00c3"
```

I know about the function `rawToChar()`, but the raw version of this character is `c3 82`. How can I get that from 00c3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
library(stringi)
stri_unescape_unicode(paste0("\\u","00c3"))
#[1] "Ã"
```

You may also want to check out [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17771985/7128934).

Comment: Oh, thanks, I knew there must be a way with `parse()`, but couldn't figure it out. (I see that that's not the point of that answer, but it was bothering me that I couldn't figure it out)