# R - How to include symbols/equations in data frame variable names?

Tags: r, parsing, variables, expression, naming

Let's say I have a `tibble` data frame called `df` in R like this:

```
df <- tibble(a = 1:3, 
             b = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

It is fairly easy to rename the variables with `dplyr::rename()` (or create new ones with `dplyr::mutate()`) including unquoting with the `:=` operator, e.g.:

```
df <- df %>% 
    rename("the new b" := b) %>%
    mutate(c = a + 1)
```

Which gives me:

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a `the new b`     c
  <int> <chr>       <dbl>
1     1 a               2
2     2 b               3
3     3 c               4
```

However, when I want to include math symbols or equations in the variable names with `expression()`, it doesn't work, e.g. when I try to use the Greek alpha symbol it fails:

```
# Fails:
> df <- df %>% 
+     mutate(expression(A~symbol:~alpha) = c)
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"df <- df %>% 
    mutate(expression(A~symbol:~alpha) ="

# Fails again:
> df <- df %>% 
+     mutate(expression(A~symbol:~alpha) := c)
Error: The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol
```

**EDIT/UPDATE**: To be clear, in the example above I want to get the actual Greek alpha symbol (*not* the string of alphabet characters "alpha").

**FURTHER EDIT**: Here's a complex example. What if I want something like this *as the variable name*:

[image: complex math equation with big sigma and division]

Possible use cases for the complex example are for `facet` labels when plotting with `ggplot2::facet_wrap()` or rendering a data frame as a table with `rmarkdown`, etc....

I've tried nesting `expression()` within `paste()` or `str_c()` to no avail. How do I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Hmm that is a complicated name.  But, don't you think it is a bit too difficult to extract values from that column by calling that as column name

Comment: It would be hard, but I was thinking in terms of when I have to produce final figures for an analyses, exporting to a fully rendered table, etc. So there will be no more calls to the data frame after that...

Comment: If the unicode values are available, may be you can create the expression with `paste`

Comment: i.e. `df %>% mutate(!! paste0("f(x) = ", "\u03B1", "/", "\u03C1") := c)`  I don't have the symbol code at the moment

Comment: Something like `df %>% mutate(!! paste0("f(x) = ", "\u03A3", "xi/i") := c)`

Comment: True. I think that's certainly more than good enough for the majority of my use cases. Thank you for your suggestions! Marking as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert it to a symbol or character and then do the `:=` after evaluating (`!!`)

```
df %>% 
   mutate(!! as.character(expr) := c)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#      a `the new b`     c `A ~ symbol:~alpha`
#  <int> <chr>       <dbl>               <dbl>
#1     1 a               2                   2
#2     2 b               3                   3
#3     3 c               4                   4
```

where

```
expr <- expression(A ~ symbol:~ alpha)
```

---

If we want the greek letter (as @hpy commented), use the unicode character -for alpha it is `\u03B1`

```
df %>% 
    mutate(!! "\u03B1" := c)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#      a `the new b`     c     α
#  <int> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 a               2     2
#2     2 b               3     3
#3     3 c               4     4
```

The above can also be extended to include some expressions

```
df %>% 
  mutate(!! paste0("\u03B1", "+", "\u03C1") := c)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#      a `the new b`     c `α+ρ`
#   <int> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 a               2     2
#2     2 b               3     3
#3     3 c               4     4
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for your quick response! Sorry I wasn't clear enough in my original question (I'll edit it), but I was hoping to get the actual Greek alpha symbol as part of the variable name. Using `!!` with `as.character()` did not do that for me, even after trying exporting the data frame to a CSV or .xlsx. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @hpy Looks like you need unicode characters to evaluate

Comment: Thanks @akrun: Does that mean I simply find the unicode codes for whatever symbol I want to use and put it in `expression()`? If so, how can equations be handled?

Comment: @hpy You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761858/converting-a-u-escaped-unicode-string-to-ascii)

Comment: OK, I just tried `mutate(!!paste0("\u03B1") := c )` and it worked! An actual Greek alpha is now the new variable's name. Thank you! I wonder, however, if there is a way to do actual math equations with `expression()`?...

Comment: @hpy Do you need something like `df %>% mutate(!! paste0("\u03B1", "+", "\u03C1") := c)`

Comment: I've added a complicated example in the original question.